# How to create new pandas series based on comparing existing values to lower & upper boundaries

Tags: python, pandas

I am creating a script that updates retail prices based on supplier cost changes.

I have successfully created a script that bring in external supplier data, matches to internal data, outputs the changes and passes these into API to update our ERP and to Sheets so we can visualise the changes.  My final task is to workout retail price changes but I can't figure out the best way to use Pandas for this problem.

df1 (priceChange):

```
      Cat Nr    Net Cost    Status
 2801   0825646183913   8.50    ACTIVE
 2802   0603497902941   7.96    ACTIVE
 2803   0603497897452   9.35    ACTIVE
 2804   4050538324761   14.45   ACTIVE
 2805   4050538307429   10.20   ACTIVE
```

df2 (priceGrid):

```
    Cost (low)  Cost (upp)  Retail
0   2.00    3.30    5.99
1   3.31    5.00    8.99
2   5.01    6.15    10.99
3   6.16    7.15    12.99
4   7.16    8.15    14.99
5   8.16    9.25    16.99
6   9.26    10.75   18.99
7   10.76   11.50   20.99
8   11.51   12.75   22.99
9   12.76   13.75   24.99
10  13.76   14.75   26.99
```

So I want to create df1['Retail'] by comparing df1['Net Cost'] to df2['Cost (low)'] & df2['Cost (upp)'] and returning df2['Retail']

For example line 2801 'Net Cost' == 8.50, therefore it would return a 'Retail' of 16.99.

df1 would look like:

```
      Cat Nr    Net Cost    Status    Retail
 2801   0825646183913   8.50    ACTIVE    16.99
 2802   0603497902941   7.96    ACTIVE    14.99
 2803   0603497897452   9.35    ACTIVE    18.99
 2804   4050538324761   14.45   ACTIVE    26.99
 2805   4050538307429   10.20   ACTIVE    18.99
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) for this.

A requirement of this method however, is that your keys on the left frame must be sorted.  Hence the need to use [`.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html), [`.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and then [`.set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html), [`.sort_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) in the example below:

```
df_merged = (pd.merge_asof(df1.reset_index().sort_values('Net Cost'),
                           df2[['Cost (low)', 'Retail']],
                           left_on='Net Cost',
                           right_on='Cost (low)')
             .set_index('index')
             .sort_index()
             .drop('Cost (low)', axis=1))

print(df_merged)

              Cat Nr  Net Cost  Status  Retail
index                                         
2801    825646183913      8.50  ACTIVE   16.99
2802    603497902941      7.96  ACTIVE   14.99
2803    603497897452      9.35  ACTIVE   18.99
2804   4050538324761     14.45  ACTIVE   26.99
2805   4050538307429     10.20  ACTIVE   18.99
```

Comment: Awesome - thanks a lot for this.  This does the job perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Another approach you could choose is to create the cartesian product and filter the rows you are interested in. You would not need to sort the data twice (which can be costly), but you might need more memory.

```
cartesian_product = pd.merge(df1.assign(key=0), df2.assign(key=0), how='outer').drop('key', axis=1)

mask = (cartesian_product['Net Cost'] >= cartesian_product['Cost (low)']) 
       & (cartesian_product['Net Cost'] < cartesian_product['Cost (upp)'])
cartesian_product[mask]

    Cat     Nr              Net Cost Status Cost (low) Cost (Upp) Retail
5   2801    825646183913    8.50    ACTIVE  8.16       9.25       16.99
15  2802    603497902941    7.96    ACTIVE  7.16       8.15       14.99
28  2803    603497897452    9.35    ACTIVE  9.26       10.75      18.99
43  2804    4050538324761   14.45   ACTIVE  13.76      14.75      26.99
50  2805    4050538307429   10.20   ACTIVE  9.26       10.75      18.99
```

Of course you can filter the dataframe accordingly.

Btw: Does anybody have a hint on how to work properly with the columns names with spaces? read from clipboard mixes a lot of things up ;)